# Enemy AI Movement Decision Making

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, game-engine

I'm working on an enemy AI movement system for a Unity platformer game that will allow the enemy to make one of three decisions on a constant basis: idle, move to the right, or move to the left. I want the enemy to be able to pick any of these decisions, even if the decision it just picked will be the same as its next decision (i.e. it can choose "move right" twice in a row, or as many more times as it wants). The script below has no errors, but when I test the game it causes my enemy to stutter around. Sometimes it moves right for a split second, then moves to the left, etc. I feel like the inherent logic of my code is somewhat correct, but the way in which it is implemented needs some work. I appreciate any help you can give me.

By the way, if I put the "MakeMovementDecision" function in the "Start" function the enemy moves .07 to the left or right, or just stand still, and never performs another movement function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AIMovement : MonoBehaviour {

// References the enemy's Rigidbody2D component
private Rigidbody2D enemyRigidbody;

// Sets the enemy's movement speed
[SerializeField]
private int movementSpeed;

// Checks if the enemy is moving (to be used with animations)
private bool isMoving;

// The direction in which the enemy will move
private Vector2 directionToMove;

// The random decision (0, 1 or 2) that represents which movement function the enemy will perform
private int decisionValue;

// The time remaining before the enemy chooses which movement function to perform again
private float timeTilNextDecision;

// The random float that will be used to determine for how long the enemy remains idle
private float idleTime;

// The random float that will be used to determine for how long the enemy moves left or right
private float moveTime;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    // Accesses the enemy's Rigidbody2D component
    enemyRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate () {

    MakeMovementDecision();
}

/// <summary>
/// Generates the decision for which type of movement the enemy will perform
/// </summary>
private void MakeMovementDecision ()
{
    // Chooses a value upon which the movement decision will be based
    decisionValue = Random.Range(0, 3);

    switch (decisionValue)
    {
        // Keeps the enemy standing still
        case 0:
            Idle();
            break;

        // Moves the enemy to the right
        case 1:
            MoveRight();
            break;

        // Moves the enemy to the left
        case 2:
            MoveLeft();
            break;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Causes the enemy to stand still with idle animations 
/// </summary>
private void Idle ()
{
    // Sets the idle stance duration
    idleTime = Random.Range(5.0f, 10.0f);

    // Calculates the time until the enemy may decide to change its movement
    timeTilNextDecision = idleTime - Time.deltaTime;

    // Sets the movement bool to false to play the idle animations
    isMoving = false;

    // Stops the enemy's movement
    enemyRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;

    // Checks if the enemy should make a decision on its next movement
    if (timeTilNextDecision < 0)
    {
        MakeMovementDecision();
    }

}

private void MoveRight()
{
    moveTime = Random.Range(2.0f, 5.01f);
    timeTilNextDecision = moveTime - Time.deltaTime;
    isMoving = true;
    directionToMove = Vector2.right;
    transform.Translate(directionToMove * (movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime));

    if (timeTilNextDecision < 0)
    {
        MakeMovementDecision();
    }

}

private void MoveLeft()
{
    moveTime = Random.Range(2.0f, 5.01f);
    timeTilNextDecision = moveTime - Time.deltaTime;
    isMoving = true;
    directionToMove = Vector2.left;
    transform.Translate(directionToMove * (movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime));

    if (timeTilNextDecision < 0)
    {
        MakeMovementDecision();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you calling your MakeMovementDecision in FixedUpdate() and the decisions in itself ? try removing `FixedUpdate()` and placing the function `MakeMovementDecision()` inside `Start()`...

Comment: Yes, I have tried that (I edited my original post to include a note about this). It simply moves the enemy by 0.07 units left or right, or chooses the "idle" variant, but then the enemy never moves again. Without looking at the x value in the inspector it would not be possible to perceive that the enemy is moving at all.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I was a victim of overscripting. This is much simpler and does exactly what I want. The key is the `timeTilNextMovement` variable being the only variable determining when the next movement will occur. I had been using way too many variables to do this simple task in my other script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D enemyRigidbody;

private int movementValue;

private float timeTilNextMovement;

private bool isMoving;

[SerializeField]
private float movementSpeed;

private Vector2 moveRight;
private Vector2 moveLeft;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    enemyRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    moveRight = Vector2.right;
    moveLeft = Vector2.left;

    MakeMovementDecision();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    timeTilNextMovement -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    switch (movementValue)
    {
        case 0:
            Debug.Log("IDLE"); 
            isMoving = false;
            enemyRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            break;
        case 1:
            Debug.Log("RIGHT");
            isMoving = true;
            transform.Translate(moveRight * (movementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
            break;
        case 2:
            Debug.Log("LEFT");
            isMoving = true;
            transform.Translate(moveLeft * (movementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
            break;
    }

    if (timeTilNextMovement < 0)
    {
        MakeMovementDecision();
    }

}

private void MakeMovementDecision()
{
    movementValue = Random.Range(0, 3);
    timeTilNextMovement = Random.Range(2.0f, 5.0f);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the time inside `FixedUpdate()`. Your code is suppose to look something like this;

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    // Calculates the time until the enemy may decide to change its movement
    moveTime += Time.deltaTime;
    timeTilNextDecision = idleTime - moveTime;

    if (timeTilNextDecision < 0)
    {
        MakeMovementDecision();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Generates the decision for which type of movement the enemy will perform
/// </summary>
private void MakeMovementDecision ()
{
    // Chooses a value upon which the movement decision will be based
    decisionValue = Random.Range(0, 3);

    switch (decisionValue)
    {
        // Keeps the enemy standing still
        case 0:
            Idle();
            break;

        // Moves the enemy to the right
        case 1:
            MoveRight();
            break;

        // Moves the enemy to the left
        case 2:
            MoveLeft();
            break;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Causes the enemy to stand still with idle animations 
/// </summary>
private void Idle ()
{

    // Sets the idle stance duration
    idleTime = Random.Range(5.0f, 10.0f);
    // Sets the movement bool to false to play the idle animations
    isMoving = false;

    // Stops the enemy's movement
    enemyRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;

    // Checks if the enemy should make a decision on its next movement


}

private void MoveRight()
{
    moveTime = Random.Range(2.0f, 5.01f);
    isMoving = true;
    directionToMove = Vector2.right;
    transform.Translate(directionToMove * (movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}

private void MoveLeft()
{
    moveTime = Random.Range(2.0f, 5.01f);
    isMoving = true;
    directionToMove = Vector2.left;
    transform.Translate(directionToMove * (movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

Edit: I found out you were calculating the time passed in a wrong way. Time.deltaTime is a fixed parameter it does not return the time passed.

Comment: Thank you for working with me on this, but this solution has also resulted in what I originally mentioned about putting MakeMovementDecision () in the Start () function.

Comment: @Dalsia yeah I realized that you were also calculating the time passed in a wrong way, try the edited `FixedUpdate()` function

Comment: Hmm, seems to be resulting in the original problem again (where it stutters violently back and forth). I don't understand why this wouldn't work, it seems to make sense, and I had forgotten that you needed to set a variable to Time.deltaTime. I tried a few different arrangements with this change with no success.

Comment: shouldnt it be `Time.fixedDeltaTime` if you use FixedUpdate? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html

Comment: I think the problem is that `timeTilNextDecision` is registering as less than 0 faster than it can be reset after the first movement decision is made. After including Debug.Log messages in the switch statement it appears that the enemy is choosing among the 3 movement options too quickly, sometimes registering different movements 10 times per second.